# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib' while making chatbot

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot

So I'm following a tutorial and making a chatbot in python and I'm using the `tflearn` and `tensorflow` modules, and when I run my code I get the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Coding Projects/chatbot/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tflearn/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tflearn/config.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .variables import variable
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tflearn/variables.py", line 7, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'
```

I can't figure out how to fix it, and was wondering if someone could help me.

Comment: what happens if you import `tensorflow` and try to access `tensorflow.contrib` that way

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

check your tensorflow version(you can to check it like that)
`

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
`
```

tensorflow contrib was removed from tensorflow 2.0 and its functionallty was moved to other modules.